# How to remove the battery icon in android status bar?

Tags: android, battery

I've removed the status bar which shows network, battery and time information in Android by take off the background image. But the icons are still there.
Just wanna know how to remove the battery icon as well.

Not for apps but for framework development.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What for do you need this? Tell us more about your app

Comment: I'm not developing app... It's for a new product. Thus I have to design an entirely new UI and remove the things I don't need for keeping it clean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working on Android 2.2, you can remove it by the following step.

1. Find StatusBarPolicy.java
2. Find mBatteryIcon and add `service.setIconVisibility(mBatteryIcon , false);` for it.
3. Remove all actions relevant to battery in the intent-filter

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried to call

```
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

in Activity onCreate() ?

Comment: Sorry for that I did not make the description clear enough. I'm not writing an app but for developing a kind of special framework. Thanks for the efficient reply anyway. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Question Owner did not want this. Anyway I exactly want this so Voted up for it