# Displaying an icon in status bar when my task is running

Tags: android, statusbar

I am creating an android service which will start running after the device boot process completed. In my service i am creating a task. This task will be started or stopped at any time depending on some conditions. My intention is whenever i started my task, i want to display an icon in status bar to know that my task is running like bluetooth icon will be displayed when it is turned ON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show an icon in the status bar when application is running, including in the background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973208/how-to-show-an-icon-in-the-status-bar-when-application-is-running-including-in)

Answer (score 7):

You need a [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html). Code is talking :)

In your Service:

```
private NotificationManager mNM;
private int NOTIFICATION = 10002; //Any unique number for this notification
```

To show the notification:

```
private void showNotification() {
    // In this sample, we'll use the same text for the ticker and the expanded notification
    CharSequence text = getText(R.string.local_service_started);

    // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.status_icon, text, System.currentTimeMillis());

    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.local_service_label), text, contentIntent);

    // Send the notification.
    mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
}
```

and to hide it, you simply do this:

```
mNM.cancel(NOTIFICATION); //The same unique notification number.
```

Here are some clarifications:

- `R.drawable.status_icon` : Notification icon
- `R.string.local_service_started` : Notification title
- `R.string.local_service_label`  : Notification latest info (sub-title)
- `MainActivity.class` : The Activity that will be launched when the user click the notification

Comment: I think notification is different from status bar icon. I mentioned like Bluetooth icon displayed on status bar. I think your answer is not suitable for my requirements. Anyhow thanks for responding to my question.

Comment: You mean like an icon that the user will never interact with? Like the 3G icon, sync and the headphone?

Comment: There is a class in Android source code called [StatusBarPolicy.java](http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/server/status/StatusBarPolicy.java.html). In the constructor, every icon that may appear in the status bar is initialized and set to visible or invisible (as needed). You may refer to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922878/how-to-remove-the-battery-icon-in-android-status-bar) for more info.

Comment: And to answer your question, I don't think it is possible for apps other than system apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Custom title bar like
[Custom title with image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086989/custom-title-with-image)

And Check the preference setting that your service is enable or disable and set custom title. but before doing this please Read :  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Custom title is different from status bar icon. Actually in my app no activity, its a service launched automatically after device booted. Is it possible to use custom title without activity in app ? Anyhow thanks for your answer.

Comment: yes, its possible to start service without any activity at all... just start your service as Foreground. You'll be providing a notification object in order to start service